# Only one 'read more' on page works

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted a page with several posts with a 'read more' option. I found some code on google, but it only works once. When I try to add another 'read more' option, it still opens the first one.

I've tried copying the JS and changing the name, but that doesn't work either.

Here's the html:

```
<section class="resume-section p-3 p-lg-5 d-flex align-items- 
center">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <p style="text-align: justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam porttitor feugiat ipsum quis 
ullamcorper. Nullam vitae velit vitae tortor semper tempor ac vitae 
magna. Maecenas a ullamcorper neque. Aliquam vitae tortor luctus  
risi rutrum eleifend non non leo.</p>

<div id="collapse" style="display:none;">
    <p style="text-align: justify;">Sed eleifend lectus id semper 
accumsan. Sed lobortis id ligula eget blandit. Integer interdum 
iaculis nunc, sed porttitor magna tincidunt in. Interdum et 
malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam lobortis 
accumsan tempor. Aliquam sollicitudin pulvinar est, quis convallis 
tellus.</p>
</div>
<a href="#collapse" class="nav-toggle">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Here's the JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
        var toggle_switch = $(this);
        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                toggle_switch.html('Read More');
            } else {
                toggle_switch.html('Read Less');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you duplicating IDs?

Comment: I've tried copying the JS and then changing the name, but that didn't work either. (I make a nav.toggle2, but that's the only part I changed, I'm new to JS)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using IDs for this sort of thing, as jquery provides ways of easily targetting elements in the page without using IDS. In your case you could target the DIV you want to collapse by using

```
var collapse_content_selector = $(this).prev();
```

instead of

```
var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
```

This will reference the DIV element in the page immediately before the anchor being clicked on. Then you can remove id="collapse" from the DIV as it isn't needed, and you can add as many as you want without having to edit the IDs in each one to make them unique.

Comment: Okay, so it seems to work offline, however, when I publish it, it doesn't work. I had to add custom styles in the head tags and I'm thinking that may me the reason. (These: <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>